# Is $R^I$ $\overline{I}$-adically complete?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $I \subset R$ an ideal such that $R$ is $I$-adically separated and denote by $R^I$ the $I$-adic completion of $R$ with respect to $I$. Let $\overline{I}$ be the closure of $I$ in $R^I$:

> Is $R^I$ $\overline{I}$-adically complete?

The answer seems to be yes. I have taken this result from a paper I am trying to understand. However I can't prove the result, which has been bugging me for a while now. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by $\bar{I}$ exactly? I will assume you see $\hat{R}$ as an $R$-module with the induced $I$-adic topology and want $\bar{I}$ to be the closure of $I \hat{R}$ with regard to that topology; which is then just $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (I \hat{R} + I^n \hat{R}) = I \hat{R}$. At least that is the notation that makes most sense to me here (e.g. one could also consider the closure of the submodule $\mathrm{im}(IR) \subseteq \hat{R}$, which should in general not be an ideal; or you could equip $\hat{R}$ with the limit topology, see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07E7).)

If $I$ is finitely generated, what you ask is true. For example, see  [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05GG).

If $I$ is not finitely generated, there are counterexamples. For example, see [the discussion here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By $\overline{I}$ I mean exactly what you wrote on the first place, though I am trying to avoid any reference to $R$-modules and such.  Thank you for the reference to the theorems you link. I should have mentioned (I will edit the question accordingly) that we are taking the ideal $I$ so that $R$ is $I$-adically separated. Does that change the result so we can indeed assure that $R^I$ is $\overline{I}$-adically complete?

Comment: The example from the stacksproject is separated.

Comment: I see... and what if $\hat{R}$ was equipped with the limit topology? Then it would be $I$-adically complete, right? Then it would also be $\overline{I}$-adically complete as well, since the closure as you write above would be just $I \hat{R}$.

Comment: I think I might have mixed up the topologies since then the result doesn't make any sense.